# Using group by to get 'Not In' data not working

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a query as follows

```
Select comp.*,emp.emp_name, emp.emp_dept
from Company_tbl comp, Employee emp
where comp.comp_id=emp.comp_id
and comp_id = 1234;
```

This produces following result

```
Comp_ID     Comp_Name   emp_name    Emp_dept
1234        Comp1234    ABCD        Admin   
1234        Comp1234    EFGH        HR
1234        Comp1234    IJKL        Admin   
1234        Comp1234    MNOP        Admin
```

From this result, I can get all the departments in EMP_dept column of a perticuar company (1234)
Now I want all those companies in which there is no HR department.

I tried using group by comp_id and emp_dept not in 'HR' but it didnt work.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want a query similar to that the you have written, but asking for all the companies that do no have a HR department? Not also that you have a syntactic error in your query: two where keywords.

Comment: Yes, I just want to fetch all those companies NOT having HR department

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
AND comp.comp_id NOT IN ( SELECT comp_id FROM Employee WHERE emp_dept = 'HR' )
```

The new select gets you all comp_ids of your employees that are in a department called "HR".
The "NOT IN" excludes these comp_ids from the result.

Comment: This one is simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of solutions is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12bce/1)</sup>

```
select c.*, e.emp_name, e.emp_dept
  from company_tbl c join employee e on e.comp_id = c.comp_id
  where not exists (
     select 1 from employee 
       where comp_id = c.comp_id
         and emp_dept='HR' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `group by` and `having` clauses:

```
select c.comp_id
     , c.comp_name
from company_tbl c join employee e on c.comp_id = e.comp_id
group by c.comp_id
       , c.comp_name
having count(case when e.emp_dept = 'HR' then e.emp_dept end) = 0
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12bce/9)